# Trying to control course content visibility to a moodle group

Tags: moodle

I am using moodle 2.2.4.

I have students in a course from district 1 and district 2.  I have a request that the student in district 2 be assigned an advisor in the course.  The advisor must only see the data of the student in district 2.

This is how I am trying to accommodate the request.

```
I created a new role called advisor based on the student role.
I created a new group in the course called group1.
I created a new account called group2_advisor 
I enrolled group2_advisor in the role of advisor into group1 in the course. 
I moved the student into group1.
```

When I log in group2_advisor, I can see just the district 1 student (which is great), BUT, I still see district 1 data when I click on the forum or quiz activities.

I initially based the advisor role on the non-editing teacher role, but that still showed both districts even after I had completed steps 1-4.  When I based the advisor role on the student role I was only able to see the district 2 data (which is what i am after).

Any insights are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Moodle group default feature [group content visibility](http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Available_for_group_members_only).